# Directly generate XYZ tiles from GeoJSON?

Tags: geojson, tiles, mbtiles, xyz

I would like to directly generate XYZ (=raster) tiles from a ~20 GB large GeoJSON file.

- This is way too much for QGIS Tiler.
- As another trick I've generated vector MBTiles from the GeoJSON, but sadly [mbutil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil) only produces garbage tile PNGs.
- GeoServer randomly omits objects at higher zoomlevels, but I need to see ALL building at every zoomlevel.

Do you know any other solution for directly generating XYZ tiles?

Comment: [Yitzhak Melamed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/125239/yitzhak-melamed), have you checked [MapTiler](https://www.maptiler.com/) or [TileMill](http://tilemill-project.github.io/tilemill/)?

Comment: Tilemill is very old, but I actually do some work with Kosmtik. But this "eats" only data imported into PostGIS!

Comment: @YitzhakMelamed which tile format? PBF?

Comment: @pathmapper {x}/{y}/{z} tiles for Tile Map Service!

Answer (score 2):

I think Mapbox tool tippecanoe is what you are looking for... https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe

Comment: Tippecanoe generates vector tiles (MBTiles) from GeoJSON. I would like to do the OPPOSITE!

Comment: You may want to edit your question then. 'directly generate XYZ tiles from a ~20 GB large GeoJSON file' EDIT. ogr2ogr should be able to take in tiles and create a geojson out of them.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be what you want to hear, but ArcGIS Server or Image Server using a mosaic and tile cache for all 20 levels.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your trying to do build vector tiles or raster tiles from your GeoJSON vector data?